# how to make a button fixed at top of the page even if the page is scrolled in silver light?

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I want to have three button at top of the page which stay visible if the page scrolled,
(I've tried separating  the other contents from buttons by scroll viewer but I don't want to have  scroll viewer in my content).any one knows how to have sticky panel or how to make button fixed at the top of page regardless of page scrolling??

I've tried below but I don't want to have scroll viewer in my code.

```
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel  Grid.Row="0">
        //My Buttons
        </StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
       //My Content
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can easily get this effect by setting the property VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Hidden.

scroll bar don't appear on the page but you can scroll the page down.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
         //your content goes here
    </ScrollViewer>
```